# Firebase + Ionic - Delete Push notification after it has been sent

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using Firebase as my backend and Ionic 4 as my frontend.

Sometimes, I send from my backend Push Notifications to notify the client of something that is happening right now. But the thing is, after a while the push notification becomes irrelevant (I can't predict when the push will be irrelevant).

I was wondering if it's possible to send a push notification that removes the old push notification, or in any different way (Just like Whatsapp closes the notifications when I read the messages via Web or App).

PS - I'm not sure if it's more related to Firebase or to Ionic

**Edit 1** - I tried to send a new notification with the same `tag`, but without `title` and `body`, but it just removes the body and keeps the title.

Comment: how abt setting a time-out for your message? is that wt you need?

Comment: @jackycflau not quite. I can't predict when the event will be over.

Comment: for my experience, your example of whatsapp can be achieved in android by using the `NotificationManagerCompat.cancelAll()` from Android API. i dont know ionic4 but you may try to find whether ionic4 expose similar API for you